# Need Tamil Bible open data source

Tags: data-request

I need the royalty free tamil bible datasource.datasources can be any format (JSON,XML,SQL etc.....).The data source format not the problem. Where i can find?

I found the open datasource for english bible in GitHub, but i can't find the datasource for tamil

Comment: http://wordplanet.org/tm/index.htm appears to have fairly relaxed licensing requirements. Quoting http://www.wordplanet.org/contact/disclaim.htm: "The Bible content of this webpage is Public Domain and it may be used in accordance with the Licensing agreement below to protect the Author as well as Distributors." (which is a contradiction, since public domain means you can't have a licensing agreement).

Answer (score 4):

#### Wikisource has Tamil Bible text

[திருவிவிலியம்](https://ta.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B2%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%AF%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D)

Wikisource is operated by Wikimedia Foundation, who also provide Wikipedia. Wikisource is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution, Share Alike license. In short, there is no license fee, but you are required to give appropriate credit to the source and you are also obligated to distribute any derivative works under the same Creative Commons Attribution, Share Alike license.

You can access this content through the Wikipedia API.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/godlytalias/Bible-Database/master/Tamil/bible.json) is what i could find.

You can host it in any NoSQL server, may be node, or import it to Mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Tamil Bible is somewhat tricky because the Bible Society of India (BSI) version most protestants use is not under a shareable license. But the older version of the Bible is in the public domain. The Bible can be found in [this](https://github.com/tfbf/Bible-Tamil-Sathiyavedam-1957) git repo. It is in USFM format.

If you find USFM hard to keep track of, I actually wrote a script to convert USFM to markdown and the markdown version can be found in my fork [here](https://github.com/berinaniesh/Bible-Tamil-Sathiyavedam-1957). Inside the md folder, you will find the Bible in GitHub flavoured markdown.